# If a public function is called from another plugin, how can I use the options of the public function's plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to allow one of the functions in my plugin (Plugin A) to be used by another plugin (Plugin B, Plugin C, etc).

Plugin A naturally has user definable options. When Plugin B called the function in A, I want B to be able to reference which object / array of options B wants to use.

If I'm within A, then getting the options and passing them into the function is simple enough. But B won't have that luxury. The only thing B will know is of the options specified which to use. It won't know the values there of.

Should I use .data() to stash the options somewhere so I can always access them? If so, a link to an example or two might help.

I hope I'm asking the right question(s)? And once again, please type slow, I'm still learning. Thx.

-- ADDED: at 50,000 ft example --

I have a plugin for Google Analytics that on("click",...) of a link does the _gaq.push(). See this for details if you're not familiar w/ GA and Event Tracking:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Anatomy

One of the things the plugin does is to define default of the GA ET parms. For example, instead of having to repeat the same settings over and over, as is the case with Google inline only approach, the plugin can define an object of settings and then on the link use the data attribute to specify which object (of setting) to plug into _gaq.push().

I'm good up to this point.

However, since the first iteration of my plugin I've come to realize there are other plugins where I could use the Google notification function in my plugin. For example:

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

I could define a Way Point and then say "Ok, fire the GA event and send GA the settings" when the scrolling hits that way point. If Way Points is only asking to a function, how can I left that function get the default / options?

Again, pardon my not using the right lexicon. I'm simply trying to communicate what it is I'm trying to do.

Comment: you might have to be a little more specific as to what you're trying to do , it sounds like that might be easy, or very difficult

Comment: yeah, can you give us an example (high-level is okay)

Comment: @ScottSelby - I've add more details and my real example. Hope ya all can help. Thx.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel  - I've add more details and my real example. Hope ya all can help. Thx.